# How can I convert/copy SQL query result to JSON?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I'm trying to figure out what would be my SQL query to result in this JSON format like this:

```
{
   "body": {
       "environments": {
           "lapilops": {
               "api_url": "1",
               "dlc_url": "1",
               "dlc_ver": "1,
               "site_url": "1",
               "photon_url": "1",
               "logcollection_url": "1",
               "env_name": "greatness"
           }
       }
   }
}
```

I have a table named lapilops and all the columns are included. My sql query is:

```
select *
from lapilops
where
Ticket = "1" AND
version = "1" AND
ios = "adr";
```

When I copy/convert the result as JSON format it turns to this:

```
{
    "data":
    [
        {
            "Ticket": 1,
            "version": "1",
            "os": "adr",
            "api_url": "1",
            "dlc_url": "1",
            "dlc_ver": "1",
            "site_url": "1",
            "photon_url": "1",
            "logcollection_url": "1",
            "env_name": "greatness"
        }
    ]
}
```

Do I need to add a table named "environments" and "body"?

I am running my SQL query and copying the result of the query in Sequel Pro.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to be doing a lot with JSON_OBJECT that will not look pretty if you are going to do it in SQL. Could you read it into an application and use some library to serialize the data into a JSON format?

Comment: Hi,

I'm so sorry for my late response. Based on my research, yes, I will be doing alot with JSON_OBJECT. But, so far we are stuck on searching on application or a template we can use so that we can serialize the data into a JSON format.

Anyway, thank you for your idea and if you have other suggestions feel free to comment it. THanks.